# Reflexive Closure

Tags: haskell, math

I have been working on a question about reflexive closure:

> The reflexive closure of a relation R is the smallest relation bigger than R which is reflexive. In other words, it is R with whatever pairs added to make R reflexive. Write a function (reflClosure) which takes a list of pairs (standing for R) and returns a list of pairs which is the reflexive closure of R. You do not need to worry about the order in which pairs appear in your return value.

I came up with this solution but it seems quite sloppy and lack neatness.

```
-- QUESTION 2: Functions and relations

reflClosure :: (Eq a) => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
reflClosure (x:xs) = nub ( (x:xs) ++ [ (x,x) | x <- (heads (x:xs)) ++ (tails 
(x:xs)) ])

nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
nub = nubBy (==)

nubBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
nubBy eq [] = []
nubBy eq (x:xs) = x : nubBy eq (filter (\y -> not (eq x y)) xs)

heads :: (Eq a) => [(a,a)] -> [a]
heads list = nub [x | (x, _) <- list]

tails :: (Eq a) => [(a,a)] -> [a]
tails list = nub [x | (_,x) <- list]

exists :: (Eq a) => (a,a) -> [(a,a)] -> Bool
exists x xs = length (filter (==x) xs) > 0


-- TEST SET FOR Q2
{-
Your functions should have the following behaviour:
reflClosure [(1,2),(3,2)] = [(1,2),(3,2),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]
reflClosure [(1,1),(3,5)] = [(1,1),(3,5),(3,3),(5,5)]

DO NOT WORRY ABOUT THE ORDER IN WHICH PAIRS APPEAR IN YOUR LIST
-}
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Explanation would be incredibly useful to learn from as well.

Comment: Given you have added the math tag, it's worth noting that this definition of reflexive closure is fatally flawed: it only leads to a partially reflexive relation (`R x x` is true of any `x` such that there is an `y` that satisfies either `R x y` or `R y x`). A proper reflexive closure gives you `R x x` for *any* `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nicer way to write `heads` and `tails` is the following:

```
heads :: (Eq a) => [(a,a)] -> [a]
heads = nub . map fst

tails :: (Eq a) => [(a,a)] -> [a]
tails = nub . map snd
```

It's point-free, plus it uses the more "functional" `map` rather than a list comprehension.

However, the fact that you need both means there's an even nicer way:

```
(heads (x:xs), tails (x:xs)) = (\(a,b) -> (nub a) (nub b)) $ unzip (x:xs)
```

Getting the `fst`s and the `snd`s is equivalent to an `unzip`.

Also, you can simplify the signature of `exists`:

```
exists :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
exists x xs = length (filter (==x) xs) > 0
```

since nothing depends on the input being a list of pairs.

Data.List already defines [`nubBy`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.9.0.0/Data-List.html#v:nubBy), so I'm not sure why you've defined it there.

It's not clear why you've defined `reflClosure` to match on `(x:xs)`, because all you care about (apparently) is that the list is non-empty. Perhaps something like this:

```
reflClosure :: (Eq a) => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
reflClosure [] = []
reflClosure xs = 
  let (as,bs) = unzip xs
  in nub $ xs ++ [ (x,x) | x <- (nub as) ++ (nub bs) ]
```

Comment: List comprehensions are perfectly fine. Indeed, for mapping `fst` or `snd` over a list, they can be more efficient.

Comment: I define the nub and nubBy because I am not supposed to use any imported libraries for these questions. My bad for not specifying.

Answer (score 2):

Relations are isomorphic to sets of pairs, not lists of pairs, so it makes sense to model them as such. Note that all the `Ord` constraints below are there because the implementation of `Set` needs it.

Use the standard library sets because they are fast.

```
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set
```

A type synonym to make the code easier to read:

```
-- A relation with underlying set s
type Relation s = Set (s,s)
```

Now we can write a function that gets all the members of the underlying set:

```
underlyingMembers :: Ord a => Relation a -> Set a
underlyingMembers r = (Set.map fst r) `Set.union` (Set.map snd r)
```

Once we have that, finding the reflexive closure of a relation is easy:

```
reflexiveClosure :: Ord a => Relation a -> Relation a
reflexiveClosure r = r `Set.union` (Set.map (\x -> (x,x)) (underlyingMembers r)
```

If you really need to work with lists, (you really shouldn't, though) you can `fromList`/`toList`:

```
listVersion :: Ord a => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
listVersion = Set.toList . reflexiveClosure . Set.fromList
```

If any of this is unclear, please leave a comment and I will explain more in detail.